# How to get the web element containing the error message in gmail login form

Tags: java, selenium, gmail

I would like to get the div element containing the error message when I type in wrong password so I can test login success but I keep on getting org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException

I have searched online for some solution but none have worked so far.

The rest of my program works fine- I can get the email and password elements and send data.
I am using Selenium with java

```
WebElement msg=driver.findElement(By.id("errormsg_0_Email"));
```

```
WebElement child = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[contains(@class, 'GQ8Pzc') and text()='Wrong password. Try again or click Forgot password to reset it.']"));
```

Answer (score 1):

Considering gmail page /gmail login form dynamically generates  class and ID attributes so I'd go via    normalize-text() and inner alert text analysis.

Please see my screenshot below and appropriate XPath locator:

```
//div[normalize-space(text()) = "Couldn't find your Google Account"]
```

[image]

So In your case XPath locator be like

```
//*[normalize-space(text()) = "Wrong password. Try again or click Forgot password to reset it."]
```